# PHP extract css value from string

Tags: php, css, preg-match-all

What I'm trying to achieve is to collect all font-families into an array from a string based on the 'font-family', so for example

```
 $string="
    Hi <span style=\"font-family: Arial \">text in Arial</span> 
    <br />
    A new line 
    <br />
    Hello again <span style=\"font-family:Courier ; font-size:12px;\"> text in courier font</span> 
  <br />
    Ready
    ";

    $array_fonts = preg_match_all(????);
```

So the $array_fonts should contain the values 'Arial' and 'Courier'.

Is this possible?

Comment: `preg_match_all` returns the number of pattern occurrences in the string or `false`, not an array of substrings (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). You should extract `style` attributes first with `DOMDocument` and use regex only after to find `font-family` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one. Explanation in the code in comments. If you are really intrested, I could explain the pattern too.

```
$string = ' Hi <span style="font-family: Arial ">text in Arial</span>
            <br />
            A new line
            <br />
            Hello again <span style="font-family:Courier ; font-size:12px;"> text in courier font</span>
            <br />
            Ready
';
//Initialize the result array
$fonts = array();
//Create a new DOMDocument and load the HTML string
$Dom = new \DOMDocument();
$Dom->loadHTML($string);
//Create a new DOMXPath
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($Dom);
//Get the spans
$spans = $xpath->query("//span");
//Iterate through spans
foreach ($spans as $span) {
    //Get the style attribute
    $style = $span->getAttribute('style');
    if ($style) {
        //If span has style, init an array for matches
        $matches = array();
        //Get the font family into the matches array
        preg_match('@font-family(\s*):(.*?)(\s?)("|;|$)@i', $style, $matches);
        if (!empty($matches[2])) {
            //If found font family, trim it, and put it into the result array
            $fonts[] = trim($matches[2]);
        }
    }
}
var_dump($fonts);
```

Output:

```
array (size=2)
   0 => string 'Arial' (length=5)
   1 => string 'Courier' (length=7)
```

Comment: I don't see the point to use XPath to only request `span` tags since you can obtain them with `$dom->getElementsByTagName('span')`. I don't think that the OP only want to target style attributes of `span` tags (it's probably just an example). In this context using XPath becomes again pertinent if you request directly: `//@style` or better: `//@style[contains(., "font-family")]`

Comment: Other thing, you write `$style = $span->getAttribute('style'); if ($style)` to test if the `span` tag has a `style` attribute. That works in this case because there are no fonts named `'0'` or with an empty string (in these two cases `$style` will be evaluated as `false`). Now, imagine you use the same to find the value of a `margin` that can be this time `0`. The way to test if an attribute exists is to use `DOMElement::hasAttribute` (in a condition) before using `DOMElement::getAttribute`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right. I've just developing a web page parser, and in my case, I need that. I did not thinking about this, I am not too familiar with these PHP DOM functions, so I've just copied my code and rewrote. So I would like to give a prompt solution to OP, if you feel this code is smelling, just please tell me, and I'll delete my answer.

Otherwise, I hope OP read the comments.

Comment: No, your code doesn't need to be deleted, only a little improved.